# Python, help me with this algo structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, dictionary

I have the following variable:

```
x={'Var_1': [a1,a2,....a13],]}
y={'Var_2': [b1,b2,....b13],]}
z={'Var_3': [c1,c2,....c13],]}
```

I wanto to calculate z that is given by the following algo

```
for i in x

    If x [i] > 0 ==> z= 0 
    if y[i-1] > - x[i] ==> z = - x[i]
    else   z = y[i-1]
```

I'm new in python and I don't know how obtain the variabile z without error. It is important to obtain the result in this format: `z={'Var_3': [c1,c2,....c13],]}`

Comment: When you say  `z` it's `z[i]` ? What causes you trouble ?

Comment: `x[i]` is going to be a list, not a number you can compare to 0, or negate.

Comment: The structure of `x`, `y`, `z` are unclear.  is there more than one key in the `dict` (why is there a `,]` near the end)? If not, `for i, val in enumerate(x['Var_1']): if val > 0 ... if y['Var_2'][i] ... ` maybe closer to what you're thinking.  It's unclear what you want and what you have tried to accomplish your goal.

Comment: We could consider the x y and z as dictionary with only one key. The single value (a1 b1 c1 and so on are numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its z['Var_3'] list

```
for index,xi in enumerate(x['Var_1']):
      if xi > 0:
        z['Var_3'][index] = 0
      else if y['Var_2'][index - 1] > -xi:
        z['Var_3'][index] = -xi
      else:
        z['Var_3'][index] = y['Var_2'][index-1]
```